# How to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 using SQL Server 2008 Express via stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-express

How to connect access the data from SQL Server 2008 R2 database using SQL Server 2008 Express through stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to create a linked server. See this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Next, you will need to use a 4 part name. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Server.Database.Schema.Table
```